# InvalidRegistration error in Firebase Cloud Messaging for Android

Tags: android, codeigniter, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am developing an Android app that using Push Notification feature. I need to push from server. I use Firebase for it. This is my first time using Firebase. But when I push from server using PHP and CURL, it is giving me invalid registration error.

I get the Firebase token in Android like this

```
String token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
```

Then I save sent that token to server and saved in the database.

At server, I am pushing like this

```
class Pusher extends REST_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function notification_get()
    {
        $rows = $this->db->get('device_registration')->result();
        $tokens= array();
        if(count($rows)>0)
        {
            foreach($rows as $row)
            {
                $tokens[] = $row->token;
            }
        }
        $message = array("message"=>"FCM PUSH NOTIFICATION TESTING");
        if(count($tokens)>0)
        {
            $result = $this->send_notification($tokens,$message);
            if(!$result)
            {
                die("Unable to send");
            }
            else{
                $this->response($result, REST_Controller::HTTP_OK);
            }
        }
        
    }

    function send_notification($tokens,$message)
    {
        $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
        $fields = array(
                'registration_ids'=>$tokens,
                'data'=>$message
            );

        $headers = array(
                'Authorization:key = AIzaSyApyfgXsNQ3dFTGWR6ns_9pttr694VDe5M',//Server key from firebase
                'Content-Type: application/json'
            );
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        if($result==FALSE)
        {
            return FALSE;
        }
        curl_close($ch);
        return $result;
    }
}
```

I am using CodeIgniter 3 framework for building Rest API. When I push accessing URL from browser, it returns JSON data with error as in the below screenshot.

[image]

As you can see it is giving InvalidRegistration error and message is not pushed to devices. What is wrong with my code?

### Additional

This is my FirebaseMessagingService class that show notification in Android

```
public class FirebaseMessagingService extends com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService {

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
        showNotification(remoteMessage.getData().get("message"));
    }

    private void showNotification(String message)
    {
        Intent i = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,i,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this).setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentTitle("FCM Test")
                .setContentText(message)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.info)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        manager.notify(0,builder.build());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Although I am not using codeigniter, I was encountering the `InvalidRegistration` error while sending to an `iOS` device, so I thought I would share my solution here.

I had to change **registration_ids** to **to** in PHP when sending a `Notification message` to a *single* device token, and make sure the value of **to** was a string and not an array.

Change this:

```
'registration_ids'=>$tokens,
```

To this:

```
'to'=>$tokens[0],
```

Comment: 'to' is used to send notification to one user while 'registration_ids' is used to send multiple users. We can count number of $tokens then set 'to' and 'registration_ids' condition according to that. Thanks to ask this question.

Answer (score 4):

For Java in Android Do not use FirebaseInstallation
for generating token i don't know why but it does not return the valid token. every time I receive "InvalidRegistration" when try to POST through FCM REST API.

```
{
"multicast_id": 8303815118005358735,
"success": 0,
"failure": 1,
"canonical_ids": 0,
"results": [
    {
        "error": "InvalidRegistration"
    }
]
```

}

Instead Use This:

```
if (firebaseUser != null) {
        FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId()
                .addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "getInstanceId failed", task.getException());
                        return;
                    }
                    if (task.getResult() != null) updateToken(task.getResult().getToken());
                });

    }

 private void updateToken(String refreshToken) {
    DocumentReference documentReference;
    Token token1 = new Token(refreshToken);//just a class with str field
    Map<String, Object> tokenMAp = new HashMap<>();
    tokenMAp.put("tokenKey", token1.getToken());
    Log.d(TAG, "updateToken: " + token1.getToken());
    String id = firebaseUser.getUid();
   
        baseref=sp.getString(BASE_REF,DEFAULT);
        documentReference= FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().document(baseref);
        updateDocWithToken(documentReference,tokenMAp);
    }
private void updateDocWithToken(DocumentReference documentReference, Map<String, Object> tokenMAp) {
    documentReference.set(tokenMAp, SetOptions.merge());
}
```